# nuxt-link slower than a

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I recognized that traveling on my site with nuxt-link has twice the load time of traveling over < a /> tag (comparing the initial page view). My test computer is way more powerful than my server, so shouldnt it be faster with the nuxt-link?

Below is a test example.

My questions:

- Anyone knows why it is slower or how to speed it up?
- If not, is it possible to render a normal < a /> instead of nuxt-link over nuxt config?
- If nuxt-link stays slower, should I stay with nuxt-link or switch to < a />?

### Test it with:

Fast load:

- Enter https://guessthatshit.com/home

Slow load:

- Enter https://guessthatshit.com/f3f73b99-dcd7-4361-b753-540bfb2134f9
- Go to home by clicking the image at the top left corner.

Comment: In case you tell me that requests to the api server are the reason, I only use one api call in the asyncData method for initial page load. Therefore this should not be the reason for the increased load time.

Comment: The Network Panel in DevTools shows the "slow load` initial page is loading a bunch of files, which takes several seconds. Those files are still being fetched when you click the shortcut to Home. If you wait for the initial page to completely download before clicking Home, you'll see the load time of the home page is about the same as the "fast load".

Comment: Wouldn't navigating to `<a>` break you out of the app context, ie completely reloading the page? Meanwhile `nuxt-link` is hooked up to a router presumably, keeping navigation within the app. There could be numerous things going on.

Answer (score 0):

@tony19 is right. The 'pre load' I perform with js is still running after change. Thats the reason for the slow load.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the loading of `<img />` is too slow, which causes nuxt-link to be
also slow.Maybe it was a problem with vue-router